# Swift go back to root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am new to swift but I have implemented FCM but I am having an issue. When I click the notification it loads the `NotificationsViewController` with the following code.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationsViewController") as! NotificationsViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = otherVC;
```

Once the `NotificationsViewController` is loaded I use the following code in on the back button to reassign the root view back to the normal ViewController.

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let redViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "splashScreen") as! ViewController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = redViewController
```

Once I am on the `splashScreen` it should show a quick image and then move on to the main dashboard using this code.

```
let vw = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vw, animated: true)
```

The problem I am having is the `splashScreen` code is not working when the app loads it from `NotificationsViewController`, it just hangs on that VC, but if I load the `splashScreen` without reassigning the root view it works.

So is there some other way I should be doing this? I just want to take the user to the `NotificationsViewController` when they click the notification and then back to the main part of the app when they click a back button.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to show the `NotificationViewController`, you just present it in fullscreen. You can set it by `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`. Then to go back to the main app, you just need to dismiss it. :)

Comment: I tried to use the following, but it doesn't open up the `NotificationViewController`, it just opens up the main part of the app when I click the notification drop down. I am still new to swift so maybe I didn't call something else after?

`let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationsViewController") as! NotificationsViewController
                otherVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

Comment: and you have to get the TopViewController ( which have navigation controller) to present that VC